# One Static IP - Multiple Web server - Mikrotik RouterOS

Tags: firewall

I want to expose my 2 web servers over the internet. Now I have a single public IP which is terminated on my WAN router, and I also have a MikroTik firewall, behind the firewall both web servers are available and we have different websites configured on them. we want that any web request that belongs to web server  01 shall redirect to web server 01 and vice versa. please see the picture as well.
[image: ff]

Comment: If a user's has answered your question, please mark their answer so your question will be 'solved'.  ty

Answer (score 4):

As *Microtik* seems to not have a [reverse proxy](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/cdn/glossary/reverse-proxy/) feature, you will need to implement it separately, in order to redirect requests from a specific domain to a specific server.

Here is an explanation from *Cloudflare*:
[image: reverse_proxy_schema]

A good reverse proxy could be [*Nginx*](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/), as it is quite simple to set up and widely used.

Here is a simple config file that could help you in your case:

```
server{
    # Port listen
    listen 80;

    # DNS Record for catch request
    server_name www.qwe123.com;

    # Open block for process forward request
    location /{
        # Server where traffic is transferred
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.10;
        # Include file proxy_params with general param
        include proxy_params;
    }
}
```

Of course there are a lot of options you can configure according to your needs.

Using a reverse proxy could be very useful for many reasons, here are some use cases:

- Expose a single certificate publicly (single entry point)
- Manage [access control lists](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/controlling-access-proxied-tcp/)
- Manage bandwith, number of connections...
- Implement load balancing
- Protect from [ddos attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack)
- [More...](https://www.loadbalancer.org/blog/why-should-businesses-use-reverse-proxy/)

[Here](https://rdr-it.com/en/nginx-configuration-as-reverse-proxy/) is a basic documentation about setting up an *Nginx* reverse proxy.

Here is the [official documentation of *Nginx*](https://docs.nginx.com/).

Please note that many other reverse proxy tools exists, here are some examples:

- [*HAProxy*](https://www.haproxy.com/fr/)
- [*Squid*](http://www.squid-cache.org/)
- [*Traefik*](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/)

Comment: Good answer - maybe you can add a reference to Server Name Indication. I believe this is the "missing feature" you are talking about?

Comment: Thank for your feedback, I edited my answer in order to clarify it. What I mean is that Microtik does not have a reverse proxy feature apparently.